# Power BI :: create measure that remove the last 2 characters from column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, m, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a query that targets our resourceGroupName on Azure.

The resourceGroupName looks like this:

```
hello-world-customer-prod-rg
hello-world-customer-staging-rg
hello-world-customer-test-rg
hello-world-customer-dev-rg
```

I want to remove the last `rg` from each resourceGroupName

For now I tried [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-Remove-last-two-characters-from-a-column/m-p/348020):

```
URL_test1 = Text.Start(SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[resourceGroupName]);Text.Lengh('Usage details'[resourceGroupName])-2)
```

but I receive `'Text.Start' is not a function` and `Unexpected expression Text.Length`

[image]

or [this](https://www.pbiusergroup.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=ec1bcc52-4e30-4a06-a136-123b303725f2&CommunityKey=b35c8468-2fd8-4e1a-8429-322c39fe7110&tab=digestviewer):

```
URL_test2 = RIGHT(SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[resourceGroupName]);2)
```

and I receive `Unexpected expression ;`

[image]

Nothing really seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** this seems working but it returns me the number of characters (17) and not the text:

```
URL_test3 = LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[resourceGroupName]),"-rg",""))
```

[image]

Comment: You're confusing DAX and M (Power Query). Are you trying to do this in the DAX editor or within Power Query?

Comment: Hello @DavidBacci. I'm clicking on "New measure". I cannot add a column as I'm not the owner of the dataset. So I have to use "New measure" as creating a new column is out of scope here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found the solution.

I passed from:

```
URL_test3 = LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[resourceGroupName]),"-rg",""))
```

to:

```
URL_test3 = SUBSTITUTE(SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[resourceGroupName]),"-rg","")
```

That's why it was showing the number!

It was because of the `LEN()`.